# Uploading Images on Firebase with putFile() or putBytes()?

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I wanna upload multiple images on firebase and i use putFile() to upload files...but,when i use putFile its uploading image direcly from local system and i cant compress image before uploading...on the other hend,if i use putBytes(),becose it requires to hold the entire contents of a file in memory at once,memory will be out...what i need to do,is there a way to compress image file and upload it with putFile(),not putBytes?

Thanks..

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode==1 && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        slike.add(selectedImage);
        brojanjeSlika++;
        final ImageView imageview = new ImageView(UploaderActivity.this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout
                .LayoutParams(120,120);
        params.setMargins(2,2,2,2);


        params.weight=1;

        imageview.setLayoutParams(params);


        mLinearLayout.setPadding(5,5,5,5);

        mLinearLayout.addView(imageview);
        Picasso.with(imageview.getContext())
                .load(selectedImage)
                .resize(120,120)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(imageview);
```

Comment: You can compress the local file into another local file and then upload that second file. But most image processing libraries that I know of will load the entire image in memory to resize it, so I don't think you'd gain much by this approach.

Comment: Can you tell me which is the most correct way to upload multiple images on firebase? in one sentence... thanks!